# How to selectively exclude a property from serialization based on the parent class type

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using the Newtonsoft.JSON library to serialize several objects. In some cases I don't want to serialize a property so I've used the ShouldSerialize prefix which has been largely successful in most cases. In one case I only want to serialize a property if it belongs to a specific class.

I've tried using the stack trace but it only tells me that the JSON object is calling the ShouldSerialize method. I don't need to know what calls ShouldSerialize, I need to know what parent class ShouldSerialize belongs to such as Parent.Child.ShouldSerialize.

How can I determine what the parent class name is while using the JSON object using the code sample below?

```
class Foo
{
    public SharedClass SomeProperty
    {
           get;
           set;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public SharedClass SomeProperty
    {
           get;
           set;
    }
}

class SharedClass
{
    public string SomeValue
    {
           get;
           set;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeSomeValue
    {
           //pseudo logic
           return ClassName == "Foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you pass that information in with a constructor argument?

Comment: why is SharedClass a string in your example? Very confusing...

Comment: Isn't there an attribute you can use to stop JSON.NET from serializing a property? Maybe `[NonSerialized]` works.

Comment: you could also use inheritance.

Comment: @Dirk and if not, you should create a custom attribute and not prefixes.

Comment: Unless you specifically add a reference to the owning class to `SharedClass`, there is no way it can know where its references are. You will need to find a different way to accomplish what you want. For instance, you could have 2 classes, one of which inherits from the other and adds the extra property.

Comment: Your question and code is incredibly confusing, but in JSON.NET to stop a public from being serialised you you the `JsonIgnore` attribute.

Comment: @Dirk It's just an example as I note in the comment above the line.

Comment: The point is to dynamically determine when to serialize the property based on what parent it has. The hardcoded attributes won't work in this case because they can't be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by Lasse Karlsen in the comments, if your `SharedClass` does not have a reference to its parent, there is no way for the `ShouldSerializeSomeValue()` method in that class to know what the parent class is.

However, if you are using [Json.Net 6.0 Release 6](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/135702) or later, you can work around this by using a custom `JsonConverter` as a means to selectively omit properties from the shared class (instead of using a `ShouldSerialize()` method), and then place `[JsonConverter]` attributes on the `SharedClass` properties within the appropriate parent classes to indicate which properties should be omitted for that instance.

Here is how the updated example class definitions might look.  You'll notice I've marked the `SharedClass` instance on `Foo` to indicate it should use a custom converter called `OmitPropertiesConverter` to omit the `SomeValue` property.  The `SharedClass` instance on `Bar` does not use a converter, so that instance will be serialized as normal.

```
class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(OmitPropertiesConverter), "SomeValue")]
    public SharedClass Shared { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public SharedClass Shared { get; set; }
}

class SharedClass
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code for the `OmitPropertiesConverter`.  Its constructor accepts a `propsToOmit` string which is a comma-delimited list of property names to be excluded from the serialization.  This gets split into an array for later use in the `WriteJson` method.  The `WriteJson` method takes the `SharedClass` value, converts it to a `JObject`, then programmatically removes the properties which are in the `propsToOmit` array before writing the `JObject` to the `JsonWriter`.

```
class OmitPropertiesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    string[] propsToOmit;

    public OmitPropertiesConverter(string propsToOmit)
    {
        this.propsToOmit = propsToOmit.Split(new char[] {','},
                                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(SharedClass));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
                                   JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer);

        // Note: ToList() is needed here to prevent "collection was modified" error
        foreach (JProperty prop in jo.Properties()
                                     .Where(p => propsToOmit.Contains(p.Name))
                                     .ToList())
        {
            prop.Remove();
        }

        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is a simple demo program which shows the converter in action:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new
        {
            Foo = new Foo
            {
                Shared = new SharedClass
                {
                    SomeValue = "foo1",
                    SomeOtherValue = "foo2"
                }
            },
            Bar = new Bar
            {
                Shared = new SharedClass
                {
                    SomeValue = "bar1",
                    SomeOtherValue = "bar2"
                }
            }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

And here is the output of the above demo.  You'll notice that the `SomeValue` property on the `SharedClass` instance inside `Foo` is not included in the output, but it is included on the instance inside `Bar`.

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "Shared": {
      "SomeOtherValue": "foo2"
    }
  },
  "Bar": {
    "Shared": {
      "SomeValue": "bar1",
      "SomeOtherValue": "bar2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I'm limited to using the Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: Json.Net and Newtonsoft.Json are the same library.  So if you are already using this library, then you should be able to use this solution.  Give it a try.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had a different task that needed tending to.  Initially I though you were just showing a sample makeup of OmitPropertiesConverter on Json.Net. Reading through I get it now.  I tried you code and it does exactly what I need. thanks!

Comment: No worries; glad I was able to help.