# Can JSON.NET be configured to serialize one level in an object graph?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

For example, let's say we've the following object graph: `a.B.C`.

I'd like to serialize just `a.B`, include all properties of `B` but exclude any association.

Is this possible with some setting on `JsonSerializer`? Am I forced to implement a  *converter*?

Comment: Is this a duplicate?  [Json.NET serialize by depth and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36159424/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Let me check.

Comment: @dbc Yeah, it's a dup. I've marked my own question as duplicate instead of deleting it because it's more generic and it can contribute to avoid future other duplicates...