# Conditionally ignore nested property when serializing object

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm struggling with conditionally serializing a property of an object that is a property of another object itself. Consider the following class structure:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    public string Base64Content { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

In some scenarios I want to serialize everything in the `Message` class, including all `Attachment` objects and its properties. This can be done by using a simple `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`. If I always wanted to ignore the `Base64Content` property, I could just add a '[JsonIgnore]' attribute on that property. However, there are some scenarios in which I want the `Base64Content` serialized, and in others I don't.

I though about creating a custom `ContractResolver` that ignores the `Attachments` property of the `Message` object. But of course, this ignores the whole list of `Attachment` objects and not just the `Base64Content` property.

Is there a way of writing a `ContractResolver` class that lets me ignore the `Base64Content` property when serializing the `Message` object?

Comment: Could you make new classes, with the same structure, and with [JsonIgnore] as needed? Then serialise your existing class if you want everything serialised **or** map to your new class and serialise it if you want just some fields serialised.

Comment: @mjwills that could be a solution, but would introduce a lot of (near) duplicate classes for something I hope to solve in a cleaner way.

Comment: You might be able to adapt the answer from [Json.NET serialize by depth and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36159424/3744182).

Answer (score 3):

Just create a custom contract resolver which excludes the properties passed to it while serializing and pass the `Base64Content` property in it conditionally.

```
public class CustomPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private HashSet<string> _propertySet;

    public CustomPropertiesContractResolver(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        if (propertyNames != null)
        {
            _propertySet = new HashSet<string>(propertyNames, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }

    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        List<MemberInfo> serializableMembers = null;
        var allMembers = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);

        if (_propertySet != null && _propertySet.Count > 0)
        {
            serializableMembers = allMembers.Where(m => !_propertySet.Contains(m.Name)).ToList();
        }
        return serializableMembers != null && serializableMembers.Count > 0 ? serializableMembers : allMembers;
    }
}
```

use it like:

```
IEnumerable<string> properties = null;
if (condition)
{
    properties = new List<string> { "Base64Content" };
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomPropertiesContractResolver(properties)
};
var serializedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages, settings);
```