# NewtonSoft ignore nested properties at runtime

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

According to [newtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomContractResolver.htm) documents, it's possible to dynamically ignore selected properties by overriding `CreateProperties`.

Is it possible to ignore nested properties dynamically?

As an example

```
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly char _startingWithChar;

    public DynamicContractResolver(char startingWithChar)
    {
        _startingWithChar = startingWithChar;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        // only serializer properties that start with the specified character
        properties =
            properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName.StartsWith(_startingWithChar.ToString())).ToList();

        return properties;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }
}
```

And then

```
Person person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Dennis",
    LastName = "Deepwater-Diver"
};

string startingWithF = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver('F') });

Console.WriteLine(startingWithF);
// {
//   "FirstName": "Dennis",
//   "FullName": "Dennis Deepwater-Diver"
// }
```

But what if `Person` looks like this, and we want do ignore `DriverID` ?

```
  public class DriverInformation
  {
    public string DriverID {get;set;}
    public string Branch {get;set}
  }

  public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DriverInformation Info {get;set}
    
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To run your resolver for `DriverInformation` type, you must first include `Info` property when creating property list for `Person`. Once the `Info` property is in the list, the resolver is invoked to resolve `DriverInformation` type, and you could apply filtering over its properties.

Comment: Instead of passing a single character have you considered to pass inclusion or exclusion list of properties?

Comment: @weichch do you have a sample? not sure if I'm following you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in [Conditionally ignore nested property when serializing object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011765/1262198) `GetSerializableMembers` needs to be overriden.

Comment: Good find, your question does seem to be a duplicate of that one.