# JSON.NET: Access Parent Object in ContractResolver

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am trying to access the `parent` object (or property) through the `ContractResolver` callback in order to omit certain properties in the property being serialized if it is not the parent.

I have classes which follow a database pattern. i.e:

```
Class base
  Private settings As Json.JsonSerializerSettings
  Public Property ID As Long = 0 ' all database records have an id
  Public Sub New() ' set up settings for later use
    settings = New Json.JsonSerializerSettings() With {
      .NullValueHandling = Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
      .MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
      .TypeNameHandling = Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto,
      .ContractResolver = New ShouldSerializeIfParent With {
      .NamingStrategy = New LowercaseNamingStrategy()
      }
    }
  End Sub
End Class
Class Address
  Inherits base
  Public Property Number As String = ""
  Public Property Street As String = ""
  Public Property City As String = ""
End Class
Class Email
  Inherits base
  Public Property Address As String = ""
  Public Property IsPrimary As Boolean = False
End Class
Class User
  Inherits base
  Public Property Name as String = ""
  Public Property Emails() as Email = {} ' users can have more than 1 email
  Public Property Address() as Address = {} ' users can have more than  1 address
End Class
```

When serializing or deserializing these objects, everything works using a `ContractResolver` which lower cases the keys.

I set this up like this:

```
Public Class ShouldSerializeIfParent
  Inherits Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
  Protected Overrides Function CreateProperty(ByVal member As MemberInfo, ByVal memberSerialization As Json.MemberSerialization) As Json.Serialization.JsonProperty
    Dim prop As Json.Serialization.JsonProperty = MyBase.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization)
    If prop.PropertyName = "id" Then 'ID comes lower cased, because we told it to 
      prop.Ignored = True
    End If
    Return prop
  End Function
End Class
Public Class LowercaseNamingStrategy
  Inherits Json.Serialization.NamingStrategy
  Protected Overrides Function ResolvePropertyName(ByVal name As String) As String
    Return name.ToLowerInvariant()
  End Function
End Class
```

As you can see I am ignoring all ID's and this does work, no ID's are being outputted.
Would there be any way to access the parent or even determine is there is a parent during serialization?

I would prefer not to output child ID's in the resulting json string.
The only variables I have to work with are `member` and `prop` and I cannot find any way to determine if either of these are the parent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Json.NET isn't designed to serialize the same type differently depending upon its position in the serialization graph.  It is a contract-based serializer which creates a contract for each type to be serialized, then serializes according to the contract.  For some workarounds and partial attempts to do this see [Json.NET serialize by depth and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36159424/3744182) and [How to perform partial object serialization providing “paths” using Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30304128/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I want to Ignore Serializing Json properties on run time [JsonIgnore].
So I wrote the below class :

```
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly string[] props;

    public DynamicContractResolver(params string[] prop)
    {
        this.props = prop;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> retval = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        var ret= retval.Where(p => !this.props.Contains(p.DeclaringType.FullName+"."+ p.PropertyName)).ToList();
        return ret;
        //return  retval.Where(p => !this.props.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

So when you want to use it you can do something like this :

```
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                    ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver("Entities.Contact.Address1")
                });
```

where Values come from DB like this :

```
var values = await _dbContext
                .Set<EntityName>()
                .Include(e => e.Contact)
                .Where(e => e. ..... )
```