# json.net serializing only selected nested properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, json.net, resolver

I want to serialize objects using json.net and C# .Also I want only selected properties to be inside the final JSON object returned. I have two classes

```
public class Class {
 
   [JsonProperty("className")]
   public string Name{ get; set;}
   
   [JsonProperty("tierUnitId")]
   public int? TierUnitId { get; set; }
   
   [JsonProperty("options")]
   public List<Options> Options{get; set;}
 
}

public class Options{

     [JsonProperty("idNum")]
     public int? idNum {get; set;}

     [JsonProperty("options")]
     public string Options {get; set;}

 }
```

Now I have an Class object which I want to `serialize`.

```
{   
   "className" : "Class",
   "tierUnitId" : 101,
   "options" : [
            { "idNum" : 10 , "options" : "00010011" } ,
            { "idNum" : 11 , "options" : "11110011" }
    ]

}
```

For that i  have override the `CreateProperties` method of the `DefaultContractResolver` class for  including only selected properties.Also i'm passing the list of properties to be included to the constructor of my `CustomRetrieveResponseResolver`  class which is extending `DefaultContractResolver`.

```
private readonly IList<string> _propertiesToInclude;
public CustomRetrieveResponseResolver(IList<string> propertiesToInclude)
{
    _propertiesToInclude = propertiesToInclude;
}
```

I have a list of strings `propertiesToInclude` which have the name of properties to be included.

For ex:
`propertiesToInclude = { "Name" , "options.idNum" }`

Now the problem is that in the list `propertiesToInclude`  i have the relative names of the nested properties. I know that `CreateProperties` is going to be called twice one for `Class` and then for `options` Class ( due to the `List<Options> Options` inside Class ). Is there any way of serializing in this manner ?  Like the output for the above object will be

```
{   
       "className" : "Class",
       "options" : [
                { "idNum" : 10 } ,
                { "idNum" : 11  }
        ]
    
}
```

Can Someone help me in this i.e serializing selected values with the using path of nested properties?

Comment: Json.NET is a contract-based serializer.  It defines a contract for a type, then serializes according to the contract.  So there's no (straightforward) way to use a different contract for the ***same type*** at different locations in the serialization graph.  See: [How to perform partial object serialization providing "paths" using Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30304128/3744182) for a discussion and workaround.  In fact that may be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: That being said, in your example you don't really need to filter properties by path, do you?  Filtering by a `IList<Type, IList<string>> propertiesByTypeToInclude` should be good enough, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute if you want to ignore properties when serializing/reserializing.

For dynamic exclusion on properties:

```
public class CustomPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private HashSet<string> _propertySet;
    
    public CustomPropertiesContractResolver(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        if (propertyNames != null)
        {
            _propertySet = new HashSet<string>(propertyNames, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
    
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        List<MemberInfo> serializableMembers = null;
        var allMembers = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
   
        if (_propertySet != null && _propertySet.Count > 0)
        {
            serializableMembers = allMembers.Where(m => !_propertySet.Contains(m.Name)).ToList();
        }
        return serializableMembers != null && serializableMembers.Count > 0 ? serializableMembers : allMembers;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var serializedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeObj, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomPropertiesContractResolver(new List<string>{"options"})
};);
```

To provide depth and be able to track contracts of nested properties, check this answer: [Json.NET serialize by depth and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159424/json-net-serialize-by-depth-and-attribute/36166759#36166759)

Comment: This will not work as I have to ignore properties dynamically. I have to include properties that are in the listpropertiesToInclude.

Comment: I was updating my answer. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: this will work but not for the nested properties like the example i have given. Like for "RvcOperatorOptions.RvcObjNum" your solution will not work.

Comment: I updated the answer creating a custom `ContractResolver` and overriding `GetSerializableMembers`. I haven't fully tested it yet but you can give it a try. If it doesn't work, I will create a solution and work on top of this.

Comment: Same thing this is also not working as i have used CreateProperties which also internally calls GetSerializableMembers so it is the same things. This will also not going to work for nested one's.

Comment: I think what you want to do it's tricky. I would suggest to find the properties more like to change (even all) and make them virtual. Then you can override only the ones you want on a model that will be used for serialization. This could add some more complexity to your code but it's a cleaner solution.

Comment: However, I updated my answer with a potential solution to ignore in depth by combining the current solution with another answer. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241382/discussion-between-indrit-kello-and-pulkit-sharma).