# Json.net serializing same type in a different manner

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

I want to serialize an object using json.net and c#. For that i have created a custom contract resolver that extends `DefaultContractResolver` class and also i have override the `CreateProperties` method. My class is something like

```
public class Hierarchy{

     [JsonProperty("id")]
     public int Id{get;set;}

     [JsonProperty("parentId")]
     public int ParentId{get;set;}

     [JsonProperty("nodes")]
     public List<Hierarchy> Nodes{get;set;}

}
```

Now i have an object of this class

```
      { 
        "id": 3585,
        "parentId": 0,
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 3586,
                "parentId": 3585,
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "id": 3587,
                        "parentId": 3586,
                        "nodes": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3599,
                "parentId": 3585,
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "id": 3600,
                        "parentId": 3599,
                        "nodes": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3601,
                        "parentId": 3599,
                        "nodes": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3602,
                        "parentId": 3599,
                        "nodes": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3603,
                        "parentId": 3599,
                        "nodes": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3744,
                "parentId": 3585,
                "nodes": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now my CustomDefaultResolver class is something like

```
public class CustomRetrieveResponseResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private readonly IList<string> _propertiesToInclude;
    



        public CustomRetrieveResponseResolver(IList<string> propertiesToInclude , Type objType)
        {
            _propertiesToInclude = propertiesToInclude;
          
        }

        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            // some code here 
        }
    }
```

I'm passing a list of strings to the constructor which has the name of the properties I want to include in the final object. For example if `propertiesToInclude  = { "id" }`  i will get output

```
{ "id" : 3585 }
```

Also when `propertiesToInclude  = { "id"  , "nodes" }` i will get the entire object. I know that json.net will bind some contract with Type of object so all the Hierarchy type object will be serializing in the same manner.

So When `propertiesToInclude  = { "nodes.id" }` is something like this i want an output

```
 { 
   "nodes" : [
            {
                "id": 3586 
            },
            {
                "id": 3599
            },
            {
                "id": 3744 
            }
        ]
  }
```

But I'm getting

```
{ 
       "nodes" : [
                {
                    "nodes":null
                },
                {
                    "nodes":null
                },
                {
                    "nodes": null 
                }
            ]
      }
```

This means I want to serialize the outer Hierarchy type and the inner Hierarchy type in a different way. I know that `CreateProperties` will be going to call only once and that time it will bind some contract or way of serializing Hierarchy Type object and it will use the same contract for every Hierarchy Type object independent of its position in the object.

So is there any way of defining different contracts ( or way of serializing)  for the same Type occurring at different hierarchies in the same object?

Comment: What is the pourpouse of the contract resolver it it can be deserialized without it.

Comment: I'm passing a list of strings to its constructor which will have the names of properties i want to include in serialization.

Comment: If you want to use JsonPath to specify which fields/objects/arrays should be included in the final json then prefer to use [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) and then [merge](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) them together.

Comment: @PulkitSharma As I understand you are creating object and after this using serializer. Why you just don't create object with the properties you want to include, instead of creatilg all and after this trying to delete some. Json serializer doesn' t serialize a type, it serializes an object.

Comment: The object is coming from the database and I have to just return only specific properties. I can not update the GET Query for fetching objects from database.

Comment: How does this differ from your question [json.net serializing only selected nested properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70846395/3744182) from yesterday?  They seem functionally identical to me.  The [comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70846395/json-net-serializing-only-selected-nested-properties#comment125252599_70846395) applies here also: is [How to perform partial object serialization providing "paths" using Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30304128/3744182) a duplicate?